# QTD MDX calculated value displaying differently on SSRS than SSAS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I have created an SSAS cube in SQL 2005 and included calculated members for **MTD**, **QTD** as well as **YTD**.

> With QTD measure I actually want to get the total over all 3 months of
>   the quarter, not just the up-to-date value.

Now when I browse the cube itself the number for the QTD measure is correct (total of all 3 months of the quarter) irrespective of what month of the quater do I pass as a parameter, but the report which pulls data from the cube shows the **up-to-date value** not the total of all 3 months. i.e. my report gives me the correct value only when I select the last month of the quarter. My report displays Sales targets (Committments) by the way. I wonder why is the report showing different values for this calculated field as compared to the cube? Below is the expression I used to calculate the total over all months of the quarter.

> Sum(QTD([DimTime].[Hierarchy].Parent),[Measures].[Commitment])

Please help.

Thanks,
Lungisa Dotye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this I decided to clear the data grid, removing all the cube fields from the report data or query. I added them back one by one keeping track of the cube values and I noticed that data actually matches what's on the cube browser until  when I added the field which details the number of days for each month of the quarter. With this field added the behavior of data changed, I think SSRS automatically drills down to a quarter-to-date level and disregarding the targets for the upcoming months of the quarter. I then decided to create a calculated field for "number of days" on the report level and exclude it from the query fields. And that solved my problem.

I know this may not be an effective solution but for now it worked.

Thanks,
Lungisa Dotye